# attr_encrypted gem must specify an iv - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-encrypted

I'm trying to encrypt two columns on my `User` model in Ruby on Rails. I have already successfully encrypted 6 other columns on a different table but this time I am getting the error `must specify an iv` only on the `User` table.

I am using the devise gem for authentication.

Here is my original migration to add the columns:

```
class AddPushNotificationColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :endpoint, :string
    add_column :users, :expiration_time, :string
    add_column :users, :encrypted_p256dh, :string
    add_column :users, :encrypted_auth, :string

    add_column :users, :encrypted_p256dh_iv, :string
    add_column :users, :encrypted_auth_iv, :string
  end
end
```

My Model:

```
attr_encrypted :p256dh, key: Rails.application.secrets.db_encryption_key
attr_encrypted :auth, key: Rails.application.secrets.db_encryption_key
```

When I call `User.first.p256dh` or `User.first.auth` I get the error:`must specify an iv`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of `attr_encrypted` are you using? It looks like there might be some issues with newer versions - https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/issues/306

Comment: Using 3.1 which is version with issues. I'm going to downgrade and give it another try.

Comment: @supremebeing7 I've tried the downgrade and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You might want to look an my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684140/must-specify-an-iv-attr-encrypted-how-to-check-login-and-password/52415672#52415672)