# must specify an iv attr_encrypted, how to check login and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-encrypted

Hi have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     secret_key = ENV['DB_COL_ENCRYPTED_KEY']
     attr_encrypted :email, :key => secret_key
     attr_encrypted :password, :key => secret_key
     [...]
end
```

Where I added the 4 cols to my model

```
rails g migration AddEncryptedColumnsToUser encrypted_email:string encrypted_password:string encrypted_email_iv:string encrypted_password_iv:string
```

Now I want to check if email and password are correct, but I don't know how to process:

```
secret_key_data = "my big secret 32 bits key "
email = User.encrypt_email("test@test.com", key: secret_key_data)
password = User.encrypt_password("test", key: secret_key_data)
User.where('(encrypted_email) LIKE ? AND (encrypted_password) LIKE ? ', email,password)
```

but when I do:

```
email = User.encrypt_email("test@test.com", key: secret_key_data)
```

I got this error:

```
ArgumentError: must specify an iv
```

Question is, **where do I get the iv from, and how do I encrypt to be able to test in the db if the login is right?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `rails g ... encrypted_login_iv:string` a typo, shouldn't it be `encrypted_password_iv`?

Comment: typo error, i edited my post, thx

Answer (score 1):

Some older versions of attr_encrypted have quirky (or no) initial vector (iv) handling. Be aware of the version of attr_encrypted that you are using.  I think this is your problem. Try **attr_encrypted v3.1.0** with Rails v4.1.16.

In your migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username, null: false
      t.string :encrypted_email
      t.string :encrypted_email_iv
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :encrypted_password_iv
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_encrypted :email, :password, 
                 key: 'Some 256-bit key here'
end
```

In your controller:

```
  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def server_params
      params.require(:server).permit(:username, :email, :password)
    end
```

This version/configuration works for me.